# error with ajax - laravel - crud - The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, crud

I want to implement this view, where only a few fields are loaded, out of many... with the "Asignar" button I extract the data I need to fill in the fields of the form on the right... the issue is that when change the data and hit "Enviar IP" to update, for some reason I get the error "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." But this route is configured as POST.

script from index.blade view

```
function updateData(){
    var id = $('#id').val();
    var estado = $('#estado').val();
    var modalidad = $('#modalidad').val();
    var inspector = $('#inspector').val();
    var lugar = $('#lugar').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {estado:estado, modalidad:modalidad, inspector:inspector, lugar:lugar},
        url: "/inspecciones/update/"+id,
        success: function(data){
            

            console.log('pericia asignada');
        }
    })


}
```

controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Siniestro;
use App\Models\User;

class InspeccionController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        $users = User::all();
        $data = Siniestro::all();

        return view('inspecciones.index', compact('users','data'));
    }

    public function allData()
    {
        $data = Siniestro::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        return response()->json($data);
    }

    public function editData($id)
    {
        $data = Siniestro::findOrFail($id);
        return response()->json($data);
    }

    public function updateData(Request $request)
    {
        $data = Siniestro::findOrFail($id)->update([
            "inspector" => $request->siniestro,
            "estado" => $request->estado,
            "modalidad" => $request->modalidad,
            "lugar" => $request->lugar,
        ]);

        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

web.php  - Route

```
Route::POST('/inspecciones/update/{id}', [InspeccionController::class, 'updateData']);
```

[index view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA2wZ.png)

Here is mi HTML

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <section class="section">
        <div class="section-header">
            <h3 class="page__heading">Derivar IP</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="section-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">                          
                                Inspecciones coordinadas                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <table class="table table-sm m-1 p-1 table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablita" style="width:100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Id</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Siniestro</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Fecha IP</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Estado</th>                                    
                                        <th scope="col">Modalidad</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Dirección</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Localidad</th>

                                        <th scope="col">Inspector</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Lugar</th>
                                        
                                        <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">                          
                                <span id="asignarT">Asignar a perito</span>
                                <span id="enviarT">Enviar IP</span>                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="siniestro">Siniestro</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="siniestro" class="form-control"  id="siniestro" for="siniestro" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Perito</label>
                                        <select class="form-select col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" aria-label="Default select example" id="inspector"´for="inspector" name="inspector"">
                                                    <option selected value="">--seleccionar--</option>
                                                    @foreach ($users as $user)
                                                    <option value="{{ $user->id}}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="estado">Estado</label>
                                    <select class="form-select col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" aria-label="Default select example" id="estado" for="estado" name="estado">
                                            <option selected></option>
                                            <option value="Coordinado">Coordinado</option>
                                            <option value="Ausente">Ausente</option>
                                            <option value="Peritando">Derivado a inspector</option>
                                            <option value="Baja">Baja</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="fechaip">Fecha de IP</label>
                                            <input type="text"  class="form-control"  id="fechaip" for="fechaip" name="fechaip">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="direccion">Direccion</label>
                                            <input type="text"  class="form-control"  id="direccion" for="direccion" name="direccion">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="localidad">Localidad</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="localidad" class="form-control"  id="localidad" for="localidad" name="localidad">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">    
                                    <label for="modalidad">Tipo de inspeccion</label>
                                    <select class="form-select col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" aria-label="Default select example" id="modalidad" for="modalidad" name="modalidad">
                                            <option selected></option>
                                            <option value="presencial">Presencial</option>
                                            <option value="videollamada">Videollamada</option>
                                            <option value="foto y presupuesto">Por foto y presupuesto</option>
                                            <option value="foto">Por foto</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="lugar">Lugar de inspección</label>
                                        <select class="form-select col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" aria-label="Default select example" id="lugar" for="lugar" name="lugar">
                                            <option selected></option>
                                            <option value="TH">Taller homologado</option>
                                            <option value="Taller del asegurado">Taller del asegurado</option>
                                            <option value="Domicilio particular">Domicilio particular</option>
                                            
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <input type="hidden" id="id">
                                    <button type="submit" id="asignarButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Asignar a perito</button>
                                    <button type="submit" id="enviarButton" onclick="updateData()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Enviar IP</button>
                                                      
                                                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
@endsection
```

Comment: Check your browser's network inspector. What does the request look like? Is there a redirect happening somewhere? There's no HTML here; are you sure the JavaScript function is even being called?

Comment: Also why isn't your controller method configured with a parameter for the model ID? And when you fix that, you should be using route model binding not doing manual lookups.

Comment: i add the HTML code. This redirect me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/inspecciones/update/35

Comment: Redirects are always GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `type="button"` or prevent the default action

```html
<button type="button" id="enviarButton" onclick="updateData()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Enviar IP</button>
```

OR

```html
<button type="submit" id="enviarButton" onclick="updateData(event)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Enviar IP</button>
```

and in `updateData(event)` function

```js
//accept the event as parameter
function updateData(event){
    //prevent the default action
    event.preventDefault();

    var id = $('#id').val();
    var estado = $('#estado').val();
    var modalidad = $('#modalidad').val();
    var inspector = $('#inspector').val();
    var lugar = $('#lugar').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {estado:estado, modalidad:modalidad, inspector:inspector, lugar:lugar},
        url: "/inspecciones/update/"+id,
        success: function(data){
            

            console.log('pericia asignada');
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: it does not work. Beyond the comments, I think the problem is that it tells me that the GET method is not supported, while I look at the route: list and it tells me that updateData is with the POST method. I don't understand why this happens, it's the first time it happens to me. I already tried passing several times route:clear and route:cache

Comment: Have you changed the `<button type="button" ...` for the `asignarButton` as well? Some click of button is making a GET request instead of POST. Open up dev tools > Network tab and see what happens when you click the button to trigger `updateData()` (js method) also have a `console.log` after `event.preventDefault()` to check if `updateData()` is actually triggered or not?

Comment: "{message: "Add [name] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\Teacher].",…}
exception: "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\MassAssignmentException"
file: "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dash_roles - test - copia\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model.php"
line: 433
message: "Add [name] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\\Models\\Teacher]."
trace: [{,…},…]"

This is even weirder, because in my models/Teachers I have the "name" field added

Comment: In your `App\Models\Teacher` class just comment out `protected $fillable = [...];` and insert `protected $guarded = [];` then try again and see.

Comment: dude, it worked. Thank you very much, I will see if I can finish the project. But I had a doubt... if this is the same "Model" that I use to add records... because as it was configured before it allowed me to add, but it didn't allow me to do an update?

Comment: Read about the protection against mass assignment at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment. The issue when you posted question was regarding GET request instead of POST which was due to `<button type="submit"...>` without preventing the default behaviour. Then after the error you got was regarding mass assignment. If answer resolved your first issue about GET request, you may accept the answer for the benefit of future visitors. As a side note: Laravel has one of the best documentation, refer it often.

Comment: Thank you friend for taking the time to solve. Yes, you have solved my query, I hope it will be useful. cya!!